# How do I replace a certain amount of whitespace using regex?

Tags: python, regex, calibre

I'm using Calibre to convert a PDF to MOBI, but it has trouble interpreting space-indented code blocks. The blocks contain a lot of spaces, but in a lot of different amounts. Some lines are even indented by 31 spaces.

Calibre allows for 3 regexes to do search and replace in the book before it's converted.

This is what I've tried.

```
\n( *) ( *)([a-zA-Z{};\*\/\(\)&#0-9])
```

Replace with:

```
\n\1&nbsp;\2\3
```

The problem, it only replaces one of the spaces. I want them all replaced with the same abount of `&nbsp;`.

I've also tried lazy versions of the first group etc.

Is this one of the cases where regular expressions are insufficient? I think this regex engine is the python standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this were Perl you could replace `(\G|\n)`  with `$1&nbsp;`, and if it were a regex engine that allowed limited-width lookbehinds (instead of fixed-width lookbehinds like Python's) you could replace `(?<=\n {0,30})`  with `&nbsp;`; but as it is, the only way I can think of is to replace something like `((?<=\n)|(?<=\n )|(?<=\n {2})|(?<=\n {3})|(?<=\n {4})|(?<=\n {5})|...|(?<=\n {30}))`  with `&nbsp;` . . . and I suspect that at that point you'll reach a limit on how long Calibre allows the input regex to be. :-/

Another option is to take a completely different approach, and replace    (two spaces) with `&nbsp;`  (non-breaking-space + regular space), without bothering to restrict it to the beginning of a line. I'm guessing that that will satisfy your needs?

Comment: It looks better now. I'm never going to get a perfect result, but it's definitely readable, thanks :-)

Comment: Quick and dirty hacks to the rescue!

Answer (score 1):

\s{31} would match exactly 31 white spaces, \s{14,31} 14 to 31

Comment: And what would I replace that with?

Answer (score 1):

Any reason not to just replace ALL spaces by non-breaking spaces? (`r/ /&nbsp;/`.)

It won't change the appearance of normal English text (except where the source had extraeneous double-spaces) and your code blocks will render correctly.

---

For fun, my attempt in Python:

```
>>> eight_spaces = "        hello world!"
>>> re.sub(r"^(|(?:&nbsp;)*)\s",r"\1&nbsp;",eight_spaces)
'&nbsp;      hello world!'
```

The idea is to replace one space at a time. It doesn't work because the `re` engine doesn't go back to the start of the line after a match - it consumes the string working left to right.

Note the alternation of `(?:&nbsp;)*` with the empty string, `(|(?:&nbsp;)*)`, so that the capture group `\1` always captures *something* (even the empty string.)

Comment: I have not tested yet, but i suspect that the text would not flow like it should. It's non-breakable space after all.

Comment: If I recall correctly, non-breaking space will still flow across lines - the difference is that adjacent `&nbsp;` won't be compacted into one space. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Steinbitglis Ah, you're right - non-breaking space is indeed "non-line-breaking". ;)

Comment: What may work well here is to add an additional step to this, after replacing all spaces with `&nbsp;` replace all `&nbsp;` that are not preceeded by a newline or `&nbsp;` with a space, some like the following: `s/((?<!\n)|(?<!&nbsp;))&nbsp;/ /g`.  This would preserve all of the indentation, while still having normal spaces between text (although consecutive spaces would become one space followed by some number of `&nbsp;`).